# How to send hidden input parameters in Multipart form to the server

Tags: java, html, multipartform-data

I have below HTML form. Please notice below hidden input fields have the **same name** (ie. "*days_of_the_week*").

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" method="post">

        <input type="file" name="myfile">

        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day1" value="Sunday" />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day2" value="Monday"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day3" value="Tuesday"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day4" value="Wednesday"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day5" value="Thursday"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day6" value="Friday"  />
        <input type="hidden" name="days_of_the_week" id="day7" value="Saturday"  />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Also assume that there can be any number of hidden fields in the HTML form with the same name or with different names. 
Ex:

```
<input type="hidden" name="abc" id="abc1"  />
<input type="hidden" name="abc" id="abc2"  />

<input type="hidden" name="pqr" id="pqr1" />

<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="xyz1" />
<input type="hidden" name="xyz" id="xyz2" />
```

Earlier above HTML form was not a multipart form. Therefore I could retrieve hidden input values on server side as an array using below code line.

```
// here request is the usual HttpServletRequest object. 
String[] parameterArray = request.getParameterValues("days_of_the_week"); 
// Thus parameterArray = {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday}
```

But after adding `multipart/form-data` attribute, now above code line returns `null` and Therefore `parameterArray  = null`. So as per my understanding, hidden values are not sent to the server as usual when we add `multipart/form-data` attribute.

So my questions are,

Is there a way to force hidden values to be sent to the server so that we can read them from `request.getParameterValues("days_of_the_week");` as usual?

If not, what is the best way to achieve above requirement? I can create a List on server side and fill it as below. But when there are any number of such hidden fields in the HTML form as described above, I may have to repeat `if(item.getFieldName().equals("hidden_field_name"))` condition check for each and every distinct hidden field name which is not so smart for me.

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

List<String> daysOfWeek = new ArrayList();

List requestList = upload.parseRequest(request);
for (Iterator iterator = requestList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    FileItem item =  (FileItem) iterator.next();
    if(item.isFormField()){
        if(item.getFieldName().equals("days_of_the_week")){
            daysOfWeek.add(item.getString());
        }  
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any suggestions or solutions for the above question.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but there are some questions which can help you: [hidden fields multipart form java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hidden+fields+multipart+form+%5Bjava%5D) and [hidden parameters multipart form java](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hidden+parameters+multipart+form+%5Bjava%5D)

Comment: @raul.vila Thank you for the directions. It was really helpful for me. below article gave me a very good solution. [MultipartFilter](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/11/multipartfilter.html)